# Decision Tree not capturing the variance of the dependent variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working with decision tree regressors. The number of data points are 15000, with 15 features. The problem I am facing is that even under high over-fitting conditions (I made depth = 25, min.samples on leaves = 2), the predictions have much lower variance than the dependent variable (i.e. it still under-fits). First I thought this might be a bias variance problem, however the mean of all the predictions and mean of dependent variable are equal to 9 places in decimal.

i.e. it something looks like: 
[image]

As a result, the predictions and dependent variable have a view like: [image]

One reason I can think of is that features I chose might not be important at all. However they **do** make sense.

Can someone please explain what might be going wrong here? Any help shall be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it's possible that there are simply not enough features, sometimes things that seem to make sense are not statistically correlated, you say they do make sense, but can you prove that that is the case?

Comment: If I fit a linear line with bucketing the variables in five, in 7 features I see a statistically significant trend. This might allow me to comment that there exists a generic relationship of these variables with the dependent variable. However, I included rest 8 variables thinking that even though they don't show a generic relationship but might be important at a particular node. Apart from adding/changing features, can there be any reasoning behind why I am seeing such results?

Comment: i am just saying that just because two lines match up on a graph, does not mean there is a relationship there, see http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Completely agree with you. Its just that they do hold logical relationship with the dependent variable, so it doesn't seem to be the case of spurious correlation.

Comment: @Prabhat maybe if you provided more details about what you actually did (read: code&data example) people could tell you exactly what is happening. For now, all we can do is taking guesses about *what might be going wrong* or provide [very generic answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55043865/3005167), both of which take a lot of time and are unlikely to be helpful in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of your own data aside, this in principle is not surprising behavior, once you understand what a decision tree is actually doing under the hood.

What a regression tree actually returns as output is the *mean value* of the dependent variable `y` of the training samples that end up in the respective terminal nodes (leaves). Practically, this means that the output is by default *discretized*: the values you get at the output are among the finite set of values in the terminal nodes, without any interpolation between them whatsoever.

Given that, intuitively it should not be that surprising that the variance of the predictions is lower than the actual values, the details of how much lower depending on the number of terminal nodes (i.e. `max_depth`), and of course the data themselves.

The following plot from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-tree-regression-py) should help visualize the idea - it should be intuitively clear that the variance of the data is indeed higher than the one of the (discretised) predictions:

[image]

Let's adapt the code from that example, adding a few more outliers (which magnify the issue):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

# dummy data
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = np.sort(5 * rng.rand(80, 1), axis=0)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - 5*rng.rand(16)) # modify here - 5*

estimator_1 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)
estimator_1.fit(X, y)

estimator_2 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5)
estimator_2.fit(X, y)

y_pred_1 = estimator_1.predict(X)
y_pred_2 = estimator_2.predict(X)
```

Let's now check the variances:

```
np.var(y) # true data
# 11.238416688700267

np.var(y_pred_1) # max_depth=2
# 1.7423865989859313

np.var(y_pred_2) # max_depth=5
# 6.1398871265574595
```

As expected, the variance of the predictions goes up with increasing tree depth, but it is still (significantly) lower than the one of the true data. While of course the *mean* values of all are the same:

```
np.mean(y)
# -1.2561013675900665

np.mean(y_pred_1)
# -1.2561013675900665

np.mean(y_pred_2)
# -1.2561013675900665
```

All this may seem surprising to newcomers, especially if they try to "naively" extend the linear thinking of linear regression; but decision trees live in their own realm, which is certainly distinct (and rather far) from the linear one.

To return to the discretization issue I opened the answer with, let's check how many unique values we get for our predictions; keeping the discussion only to `y_pred_1` for simplicity:

```
np.unique(y_pred_1)
# array([-11.74901949,  -1.9966201 ,  -0.71895532])
```

That's it; *every* output you will get from that regression tree will be one of these 3 values, and *never* anything "between", like `-10`, `-5.82` or [...] (i.e. *no interpolation*). Now, again intuitively speaking at least, you should be able to convince yourself that the variance under such circumstances is unsurprisingly (much...) lower than the one of the actual data (the predictions are by default less dispersed)...